# looping through a string and using repeat method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve this exercise which goal is to give me a string that has to be turned into another string. The characters of the new string are repeated like in the example below.

Example:
`accum("abcd");    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"`

I wrote the following code:

```js
function accum(s) {
  counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    return s[i].toUpperCase() + s[i].repeat(counter) + "-";
    counter += 1;
  }
}
```

When I try to run a sample test such as `ZpglnRxqenU` I get this error:

> **Expected:** 'Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu', instead got: 'Z-'.

Apparently the problem is linked to the loop which is not working, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ES6 one-liner :

```js
const accum = word => word.toLowerCase().split("").map( (letter,index) => letter.toUpperCase() + letter.repeat(index) ).join("-")
  
console.log( accum("ZpglnRxqenU") )
```

Explanation :

- `word.split("")` Start with breaking your string into an array of letters
- `.map( (letter,index) =>` Iterate each letter, keeping track of the index as you go
- `letter.toUpperCase() + letter.repeat(index)` Replace each letter with the transformed value that you return
- At this point, you have an array of transformed values
- `.join("-")` Join everything back to a string with "-" as a separator.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the use of the methods: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
function accum(s) {
  return s
    .split('')
    .map(function (e, i) {
      return e.toUpperCase() + e.repeat(i);
    })
    .join('-');
}

console.log(accum('ZpglnRxqenU'));
```

ES6:

```js
const accum = s => s.split('').map((e, i) => e.toUpperCase() + e.repeat(i)).join('-');

console.log(accum('ZpglnRxqenU'));
```

Comment: Ok I'm taking that back

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
function accum(s) {
  s = s.toLowerCase();
  const letters = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    letters.push(s[i].toUpperCase() + s[i].repeat(i));
  }
  
  return letters.join('-');
}

console.log(accum('ZpglnRxqenU'));
```

You have an array and fill it with the letters, once filled you join the elements with '-'. You could just add the letters to a string but at the end you would have to trim the trailing '-', which isn't wrong but now you have 2 ways to do this.

Also you don't need the `counter` variable because `i` is already counting.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but when I try to run your code I have this error:

Comment: Expected: 'Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu', instead got: 'Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-RRRRRR-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-UUUUUUUUUUU'

Comment: Ok I fixed it, I didn't notice the uppercase possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. When you `return` the loop will stop. You need to remove that.

```js
function accum(s) {
  counter = 0;
  sA = s.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    sA[i] = sA[i].toUpperCase() + sA[i].toLowerCase().repeat(counter);
    counter += 1;
  }
  return sA.join('-');
}
console.log(accum('ZpglnRxqenU'));
```

Comment: You don't need the `s.length == i-1` stuff. Just join the array with `"-"`

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! I tried to run your code but I get an undefined as a result. This is the error: Expected: 'Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu', instead got: undefined

Comment: @InnSaei Just use `return sA.join('-')` instead of  `console.log(sA.join('-'));` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

With array.reduce:

```js
var str = "abcd";
function accum(str) {
    var arr = str.split("");
    return arr.reduce((m, o, i) => {
        m += (i === 0 ? "" : "-") + o.toUpperCase() ;
        for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            m += o;
        }
        return m;
    }, "");
}

var ret = accum(str);
console.log(ret);
```